# Fragmentation in SQLite used in a round-robin fashion without VACUUM

Tags: sqlite, sd-card, premature-optimization

There's an SQLite database being used to store static-sized data in a round-robin fashion.

For example, 100 days of data are stored. On day 101, day 1 is deleted and then day 101 is inserted.

The number of rows is the same between days. The the individual fields in the rows are all integers (32-bit or less) and timestamps.

The database is stored on an SD card with poor I/O speed,
something like a read speed of 30 MB/s.

VACUUM is not allowed because it can introduce a wait of several seconds
and the writers to that database can't be allowed to wait for write access.

So the concern is fragmentation, because I'm inserting and deleting records constantly
without VACUUMing.
But since I'm deleting/inserting the same set of rows each day,
will the data get fragmented?
**Is SQLite fitting day 101's data in day 1's freed pages?**

And although the set of rows is the same,
the integers may be 1 byte day and then 4 bytes another.
The database also has several indexes, and I'm unsure where they're stored
and if they interfere with the perfect pattern of freeing pages and then re-using them.

(SQLite is the only technology that can be used. Can't switch to a TSDB/RRDtool, etc.)

Comment: Why do you care about fragmentation? Do you expect slowdowns? If yes, the only way to find out how much your devices are affected is to measure yourself.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is necessary premature optimization, because I'm using an embedded processor, which is slow, storing data on an SD card, which is slow. I'm worried about writing myself  into a corner if performance turns out to be a big issue later.

Comment: You said that SQLite is the only technology that can be used. So the alternative to fragmentation would be to give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite will reuse free pages, so you will get fragmentation (if you delete so much data that entire pages become free).

However, SD cards are likely to have a flash translation layer, which introduces fragmentation whenever you write to some random sector.

Whether the first kind of fragmentation is noticeable depends on the hardware, and on the software's access pattern.
It is not possible to make useful predictions about that; you have to measure it.

---

In theory, [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) is append-only, and thus easier on the flash device.
However, [checkpoints](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#ckpt) would be nearly as bad as VACUUMs.